# Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания в фразе: Думаю, чего это день-то такой хороший. А, точно - я же на успокоительных

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Нужен ли вопросительный знак после *хороший*? Вообще, правильно ли оформлено?

> Думаю, чего это день-то такой хороший. А, точно - я же на
> успокоительных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Думаю, чего это день-то такой хороший? А, точно – я же на успокоительных.***

Предложение оформлено верно, добавлен только вопросительный знак.

**Пояснение**

1. **После междометия А** ставится запятая. А, межд. 1. Выражает припоминание, узнавание при встрече, догадку и т.п.
2. **Вопросительный знак** ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если вопрос содержится и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, либо в придаточной. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Пример: ― *А я думаю, чего вы такая хорошая?* [Вацлав Михальский. Прощеное воскресенье // Октябрь, 2009]

3. **Тире** обозначает присоединительную конструкцию, иногда в таких случаях ставится запятая.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса**

― **А, точно,** в «Звездных войнах», в третьей серии. [Виктор Пелевин. Миттельшпиль (1991)]

**А, точно,** я в ней разок рылась ― столько любовных записок, мама дорогая. [Г. С. Зеленина. // «Волга», 2014]